# Can't select multiple images to upload on Android - Chrome Web Browser

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, web-applications, multiple-file-upload

I would like to create a Web App where the user can select and upload multiple images from the phone's image gallery. This function works fine on iOS, but it seems to be broken on android:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload!" />
</form>
```

I have read several posts where people claim to be fixed in the Chrome Web Browser, but I still can't get it to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

here is the code I was using for desktop:

```
<input type="file" id="deviceImages" multiple accept=".jpg,.gif,.png,.jpeg"/>
```

we thought we needed two, here's the one for mobile:

```
<input type="file" id="deviceCamera" multiple accept="image/*"/>
```

but what we noticed was that when you choose the "desktop" link it gave you an option to upload from the `Documents`, and this allowed multiple select by long pressing first.

but from the "mobile" (image/*) input it let you select from `Camera` or some apps, but not `Documents`, and you weren't able to multi-select from them.

so now i'm just using:

```
<input type="file" multiple accept="image/*,.jpg,.gif,.png,.jpeg"/>
```

this gives me access to select from `Documents` and `Camera` but not any of the apps, but at least `Documents` allows you to select multiple images.

hopefully someone knows code to allow the apps as well!

**UPDATE**

we are now just using

```
<input type="file" id="deviceImages" multiple accept="image/*">
```

this gives you the apps, but not the `Documents` on my s4.  you need to choose the right one for your site, but then the users need to know how to select multiple images based on the app that they use.  using `Gallery` didn't work as well for me, so I started using `Photos` and that allowed me to multi-select images. HTH!

Comment: multiple is a boolean attribute

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same problem, but I noticed that when I'm using the gallery app (instead of Google Photos App) to choose them, it works.

Not when choosing them from the Google Photos App.

Comment: Did  you figure out how to upload multiple photos from google photos on android phone?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple file/photo selection does work (using Android Turbo phone (running Android 5.1) and Google Chrome (version 49+)) ... it requires more than just tapping each photo, you need to actually HOLD each photo until it says "1 selected", "2 selected", etc... then click Open.